# PowerShell insert into SQL FileStream-Database a file bigger than 2 GB

Tags: sql-server, powershell, filestream

I'm trying to insert a zip-file into a sql server database (filestream is active).
No problem, when the zip-file is <= 2GB. Having a file bigger than 2 GB (4GB) I can't read the file with the method: [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes at once, so I try with a System.IO.Filestream method.
But still getting 2 errors:

1. Cannot convert argument "0", with value: "2504870328", for "Int64[]" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "2504870328" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too
   small for an Int32.""
2. Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot access a closed file."

My code looks like that:

```sh
    Function Upload-ZIPFile
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [double]$ScriptVersion,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('PS','AdminDB','SQLBinary')]
        [string]$ScriptType,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$ZIPFile,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Build
    )

    $checkSum = Get-FileHash $ZIPFile
    ## here was the orignal code, works with all files less than 2 GB
    ## [byte[]]$file = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ZIPFile)
    $file = New-Object System.IO.Filestream($ZIPFile,[System.IO.FileMode]'Open',[System.IO.FileAccess]'Read')
    $buffer = New-Object long[] -ArgumentList $file.length
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $file.Read($buffer,0,$buffer.Length)
    $file.Close()
    $conn.ConnectionString = "Server=MyServer\Instance;Database=SQL_TEAM;Integrated Security=True"

    $conn.Open() | out-null
    $cmd = new-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $cmd.Connection = $conn
    $cmd.CommandText = "Insert deployment.softwarerepository(fileID, version_nr, file_typ, datafile, checksum, build) values (NEWID(), $ScriptVersion,'$ScriptType', @insert, @hash,'$Build')"

    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@insert",$file)
    $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hash",$checkSum.Hash)
    #
    #exek
    $cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
    $conn.Close()
    $conn.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Using `AddWithValue` for this is a bad idea. Be explicit about what you're doing -- `$cmd.Parameters.Add("@Insert", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarBinary, -1).Value = $file`. (Disclaimer: I have no idea if this fixes it, but it shouldn't *hurt*.) Also, remove the `$buffer` and `$file.Read`/`$file.Close` calls (well, keep the `.Close` but move it to the end) -- you want to stream the file to SQL Server, not attempt to read it all in memory.

Comment: thanks Jeroen, this does the trick!
1. I got rid of buffer (hmm, I thougt first I have to read the file into the $file variable in order to insert it. Huge mistake
2. I put $file.close() to the end (still don't understand why have to, I didn't "open" the file?).
3. It works with explicit parameter-type as well as "addwithvalue", no problem.

Comment: You opened the stream when you `new`ed it, this implicitly opens the file. Even if it happens to "work" with `AddWithValue`, there are [good reasons](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to avoid it in general. This is especially true if your value is a bit more "exotic" like a stream, you really don't want it to be guessing at your type.

Comment: I'm surprised a `varbinary(MAX)` value over 2GB worked. I thought one had to use `SqlFileStream` with files over 2GB. That might still be something to look into for performance.

Comment: cool reading, I found: "This is much less of a concern if you’re calling a stored procedure, because the procedure parameter will have its own type, and that’s what will be checked against the underlying tables." I'm using a stored procedure.
But you're right, it doesn't "hurt" to use the proper parameter. Thanks.

Comment: @Dan: I created the table on sql server using: create table......
[datafile] [varbinary](max) FILESTREAM  NULL, the column type is varbinary(max) using FILESTREAM. On the other hand you're right, the datatype varbinary(max) has the max value ... 2 GB. Confusing. But it seems to work..and yes, doing upload (3 GB) takes on my sql server 2019 128 GB RAM 2 minutes!

Comment: You're certainly not using a stored procedure in the code you've shown -- that's just a bare `INSERT` statement. Also -- strongly consider making the parameters that are now interpolated into the string (`$ScriptVersion`, `$ScriptType`, `$Build`) *actual* parameters as well. Aside from avoiding potential SQL injection if values come from external input, you also avoid conversion and escaping problems.

Comment: @Jeroen: you're right, I mixed it up, there is another function I'm using with stored procedure.